# Variable in colnames

Tags: r

I want to combine text and a variable in Colnames. 
An example what I've tried (mix between Python and R):

```
list_names <- "Henk", "Ash", "Brock", "Piet"
list_age <- 14 , 12, 44, 56

for (i in range 1:4) {
  Colnames (df) <-  c("This is my name", list_names[[i]], "and I'am", list_age[[i]], "years old."
}
```

I tried this, but get the error that Colnames has got to many arguments.

Does anybody know how to put these variables in something like Colnames?

KR, 
Arnand

Comment: Do you need `paste` i.e. `paste("This is my name", list_names, "and I'am", list_age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `paste` (using `R`)

```
colnames(df) <- paste("This is my name", list_names, "and I'am", list_age)
colnames(df)
#[1] "This is my name Henk and I'am 14"  "This is my name Ash and I'am 12"   "This is my name Brock and I'am 44"
#[4] "This is my name Piet and I'am 56"
```

#### data

```
list_names <- c("Henk", "Ash", "Brock", "Piet")
list_age <- c(14 , 12, 44, 56)
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:4, v2 = 2:5, v3 = 3:6, v4 = 4:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifications in your for loop

```
for (i in 1:4){
names(df)[i] <- paste(c("This is my name ",list_names[i]," and I'am ",list_age[i]," years old."),collapse="")
}

names(df)
[1] "This is my name Henk and I'am 14 years old."  "This is my name Ash and I'am 12 years old."  
[3] "This is my name Brock and I'am 44 years old." "This is my name Piet and I'am 56 years old."
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste`.

Don't use `range`, as in R it means completely different thing than in Python.

Don't use lists unless necessary. Use vectors instead whenever possible.

`paste` will be happy to accept vectors, or even mix of vectors and scalars.

```
df <- matrix(,10,4)
names <- c("Henk", "Ash", "Brock", "Piet") 
ages <- c(14, 12, 44, 56)
colnames(df) <- paste("This is my name", names, "and I'am", ages, "years old.")
```

Comment: How is this a different solution.  I posted the same solution 7 mins before this got posted